# PHP is not called in HTML form

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have two problems with the following code. Firstly, my PHP script is not being called when Submit is clicked. Secondly, how do I pass the selected "Option" from the drop down menu to the mail function as the "from" parameter for the PHPMailer?

Thanks!

```
   <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host     = "STMP.BLAH.EDU"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = $email;
$mail->AddAddress("TEST.TEST.EDU");  //HOW TO TAKE OPTION FROM DROP DOWN?
$mail->Subject  = $text;
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Submit a New Request</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
</head>
<body>
<form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Submit a New Request</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Required</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="student@iastate.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
        </li>
          <li>
            <label for="name">Subject:</label>
            <input type="text" required />
        </li>
        </li>
          <li>
            <label for="name">Contact:</label>
            <select>
            <option value="OPTION1">OP1</option>
            <option value="OPTION1">OP2</option>
            </select>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Body:</label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit!</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your submit button isn't named, *so there*. Nothing will execute; **name it,** or if you don't want to do that, then change `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` to `if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){` and it will work. (lol)

Comment: Also, doing a `var_dump($_POST['submit'])` will give you an idea of the information being posted.  And you should, of course, sanitize anything being posted to your page before passing it directly to your email routine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not naming any of your elements to PHP doesn't know what to do with it.

For your submit button:

```
<button class="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit!</button>
```

For other things you need to go into the tag and add the name to it like I did above there.

If I did this with a name "test1":

```
<input type="text" name="test1" />
```

and sent it, like you're doing through POST, it could be read in PHP as:

```
$_POST['test1']
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your button to input so your form will be submit, check this [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" class="submit">
```

And your select is also not proper, `name` is always important,

```
 <select name="option">
    <option value="OPTION1">OP1</option>
    <option value="OPTION1">OP2</option>
 </select>
```

take it to `$_POST['option']`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host     = "STMP.BLAH.EDU"; // SMTP server

    $mail->From     = $email; // ??
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['contact']);  //HOW TO TAKE OPTION FROM DROP DOWN?
    $mail->Subject  = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body     = $_POST['message'];
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Submit a New Request</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles.css" >
</head>
<body>
<form class="contact_form" action="" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Submit a New Request</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Required</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="student@iastate.com" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Enter a valid e-mail address.</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
            <input type="text" required name="subject" id="subject" />
        </li>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="contact">Contact:</label>
            <select name="contact" id="contact">
                <option value="OPTION1">OP1</option>
                <option value="OPTION1">OP2</option>
            </select>

        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="message">Body:</label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="6" required ></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit!</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```